# Filezilla stopped showing hidden files all of a sudden

Tags: ftp, sftp, filezilla

Recently my filezilla stopped displaying hidden files (.htaccess, .env, etc). I have the "Force showing hidden files" option selected. I thought this might be a change at the server level, but that's not it either as I downloaded winscp and am able to connect and view hidden files. Anyone had this happen before? Know of a solution?

Comment: Show us WinSCP and FileZilla log files.

Comment: Suggest you to upgrade the filezilla  to latest version

Comment: uninstalled old version, rebooted, installed latest version, issue persists. Are there any registry entries that I should have removed after the uninstall?

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue I went to `View -> Directory listing filters`, and under `Remote filters` unchecked `Configuration files`. I'm not sure how this was suddenly enabled, but unchecking it resolved the issue.